# How to get distinct values relationizing splited column values in SQL

Tags: sql, count, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have a table like the example below.

```
+--------+--------+
|  name  | answer |
+--------+--------+
| John   | yes    |
| Dilan  | yes    |
| Dilan  | no     |
| Amanda | no     |
+--------+--------+
```

I need to reorganize the table in a way that I have distinct values in `name` column and the `answer` column split in two columns, the `answer_yes` and `answer_no`, matching the related answers from the original table.

```
+--------+------------+-----------+
|  name  | answer_yes | answer_no |
+--------+------------+-----------+
| John   | yes        |           |
| Dilan  | yes        | no        |
| Amanda |            | no        |
+--------+------------+-----------+
```

I am guessing I have to use some function that search for the values `yes` and `no` through the `answer` column, but I didn't find what function does this work... how can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select name,
    max(case when answer = 'yes' then 'yes' end) answer_yes,
    max(case when answer = 'no'  then 'no'  end) answer_no
from mytable
group by name
```

If a `name` may have more than one "yes" or "no", it would be more useful to count the values:

```
select name,
    sum(case when answer = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_answer_yes,
    sum(case when answer = 'no'  then 1 else 0 end) cnt_answer_no
from mytable
group by name
```

Comment: it has more than one yes or no, but the first solution meets my need. Thanks!

Comment: by the way, does `max` have any purpose other than just a generic agreggation function for getting distinct name values?

Comment: @WoolfDall: indeed, it is just there to aggregate. It could very well be `MIN()`, the results would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       max(case when answer = 'yes' then answer end) as answer_yes,
       max(case when answer = 'no' then answer end) as answer_no
from t
group by name;
```